# Issue while uploading last part in a multipart upload to S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm having issues whilst uploading the last part of a file in a multipart upload to S3 (boto3, python3.6). 
Below my code:

```
mp_upload = s3_client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=external_bucket, Key=audience_key)
mp_upload_id = mp_upload["UploadId"]
part_info = []
upload_content = []
byte_upload_size = 0
counter = 1
uploaded_once = False
FIVE_MEGABYTE = 5000000
for key in keys_to_aggregate:
        response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=internal_bucket, Key=key)
        byte_file_size = response["ContentLength"]
        file_content = response["Body"].read().decode()

        byte_upload_size += byte_file_size
        upload_content.append(file_content)

        if byte_upload_size >= FIVE_MEGABYTE:
            # as soon as we reach the lower limit we upload
            logger.info(f"Uploading part {counter}")
            body = "".join(upload_content)
            body_with_header = f"{header}\n{body}".encode()
            part = s3_client.upload_part(Bucket=external_bucket,
                                         Key=audience_key,
                                         PartNumber=counter,
                                         UploadId=mp_upload_id,
                                         Body=body_with_header)

            part_info.append({"PartNumber": counter, "ETag": part["ETag"]})
            counter += 1
            # freeing up uploaded data
            byte_upload_size = 0
            upload_content = []
            uploaded_once = True

    if uploaded_once:
        # the last part can be less than 5MB so we need to upload it
        if byte_upload_size > 0:
            logger.info(f"Uploading last part for {job_id}")
            body = "".join(upload_content)
            body_with_header = f"{header}\n{body}".encode()
            part = s3_client.upload_part(Bucket=external_bucket,
                                         Key=audience_key,
                                         PartNumber=counter,
                                         UploadId=mp_upload_id,
                                         Body=body_with_header)

            part_info.append({"PartNumber": counter, "ETag": part["ETag"]})
            counter += 1

        s3_client.complete_multipart_upload(Bucket=external_bucket,
                                            Key=audience_key,
                                            UploadId=mp_upload_id,
                                            MultipartUpload={
                                                "Parts": part_info})
        logger.info(f"Multipart upload for {job_id} completed")
    else:
        # we didn't reach the 5MB threshold so no file was uploaded
        s3_client.abort_multipart_upload(Bucket=external_bucket,
                                         Key=audience_key,
                                         UploadId=mp_upload_id)

        # we proceed with a normal put
        body = "".join(upload_content)
        body_with_header = f"{header}\n{body}".encode()
        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=external_bucket, Key=audience_key,
                             Body=body_with_header)
        logger.info(f"Single file upload completed for {job_id}")
```

Where *keys_to_aggregate* is a list of keys in S3.

The issue comes out inside the if *if byte_uploaded_size > 0* that checks for the last piece of data to be uploaded. This piece of data is less than 5MB, I was under the impression that you could upload as last part a file smaller than 5MB.

For some reason boto3 does not recognise that last part as last part and throws: `Error while aggregating data from S3: An error occurred (EntityTooSmall) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size`.

I can't figure a way of flagging the last upload as las part. Anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks!
Alessio

Comment: There is no need to flag the last part as the last part.  It works as you expect it to.  In fact, it even works if there is only one part and that one part (both first and last) is less than 5M.  More logging may be in order, specifically the part number and byte sizes of each part, before and at the point of failure.

Comment: It also might be that `FIVE_MEGABYTE = 5 * 1024 * 1024` (MiB) and the error is that the previous parts are all too small.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you were right. I've changed the FIVE_MEGABYTE value and it's now working. Thanks!

Comment: Boto may have swallowed part of the exception, which is unforgivably bad design, if true.  On the wire, S3 would have actually given you the answer: `<MinSizeAllowed>5242880</MinSizeAllowed>`.

Comment: That is the only part I can see of the exception. Thanks a lot for your help @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `EntityTooSmall`
>
> Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed object size. Each part must be at least 5 MB in size, except the last part.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadComplete.html

Reading between the lines, this error isn't about your last part -- it's about one or more previous parts.

From this, it appears that the minimum part size is not actually 5 MB (5 × 1000 × 1000) but is in fact 5 MiB (5 × 1024 × 1024).